# Angular Material with Angular 7

Tags: angular-material

I'm new to angular, but we are implementing Angular material for the popup functionality.
In the app.module.ts I'm importing the MatButtonModule and MatDialog module with the following import statements.

```
import {MatButtonModule} from "@angular/material/button/typings/button-module";
import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-module";
```

For some reason when I compile, using ng build, I get the error message below.

```
ng build

Date: 2020-05-04T18:47:12.434Z
Hash: 9bec1eb21effd8a26717
Time: 10607ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 426 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 425 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 200 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 5.56 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/button/typings/button-module' in 
'C:\Code\AFI\bugs\68550\Hpfc.Afi.Web\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-module' in 
'C:\Code\AFI\bugs\68550\Hpfc.Afi.Web\src\app'

Here are my versions
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 12.16.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.15
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core            0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      0.7.5
@angular/animations             7.2.16
@angular/cdk                    7.3.7
@angular/cli                    7.3.9
@angular/material               7.3.7
@ngtools/json-schema            1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                7.3.9
@schematics/angular             7.3.9
@schematics/package-update      0.7.5
@schematics/update              0.13.9
rxjs                            6.5.4
typescript                      3.2.4
webpack                         4.29.0
```

What am I missing or not doing correctly to get those error message?

Answer (score 0):

In order to import these modules you also need to add them to the module where you want to use them, E.g: app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, MatButtonModule, MatDialogModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Then you should be able to use both of them in all the components that belong to that module